# Strange IONIC error message

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am very new to Ionic and currently working my way through a few tutorials, specially around authentication. I have been getting the following error all day:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null(…)
onloadwff.js:1569
```

I am able to get rid of this error message by setting the following variable with a values:

```
    vmLogin.user = {
        username: 'testaccount',
        password: 'testaccount'
    };
```

I then do not get the error message. However, when I logout and back in again I do. I am aware that I am not sharing my full code but any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Dan

Comment: You have to share the part of your code that you use the `getElementsByTagName` at least. In my believe is that you haven't initiate the user object but I have to see how you use it first.

Comment: @VassilisPits this is the problrem I am having. When I review the code I have written I am not using getElementsByTagName tag. So this makes it very confusing as to why I am getting the error.

Comment: The file `onloadwff.js` is connected to LastPass for Chrome plugin - try disabling it?

Comment: @canisminor you've solved my problem but also made me cry! I spent all day on this issue. Many many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who may also discover this issue. Ensure you have browser extensions disabled. In my case, as pointed out by @canis minor it was LastPass causing the errors.  Many thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm using mainly Chrome. When I do stuff in Ionic, I usually open an incognito tab.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova very good suggestion. In future I will do. I have never come across this type of error previous. Only when I cross over to displaying content via ionic-lab. Good error to know for the future.